# How to enable team site calendar on a publishing site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, publishing-site, sharepoint-calendar, team-sites

I am using SharePoint 365 online (modern)

I have a publishing site, but I want to use the calendar which is available on a team site.

Is there a way to enable calendar on a publishing site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable Collaboration features on Publishing sites by referring to the article below:

https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/04/04/how-to-enable-collaboration-features-on-publishing-sites/

In addition, you can enable the “Office SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features” and “Office SharePoint Server Standard Site features”, which prevents a lot of the typical SharePoint functionality from being available in publishing sites.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below :-

1. Go to Site Settings
2. Click on Manage Site Features under Site Actions
3. Activate the Team Collaboration lists feature

Now you can use Calendar.

Let me know if any issues.